# Equal height images in flexbox with unknown aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive, responsive-images

I have images in a horizontal flex container. They should all be responsive, have the same height, while keeping their aspect ratio, and without being cropped:

[image: same height images in flexbox]

This can be accomplished with this CodePen: https://codepen.io/sarus/pen/PJGPmy

The main problem with this approach is that you need to know the aspect ratios of all images in advance:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.pics_in_a_row {
  display: flex;
}

.img1 { flex: 1.3344; }
.img2 { flex: 1.3345; }
.img3 { flex: 0.7505; }
```

Is there a way to make this work with arbitrary images and unknown aspect ratios, with pure CSS (no JavaScript)?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the css property     `object-fit`.

```
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, it's not what I asked. This gives the images a fixed height and width. Also, it crops the images. Let me know if I can update the question to clarify somehow.